# Scrolling screen in altium 16

Tags: altium

I'm a totally newbie to altium and there's one thing that totally annoys me: I don't see any scrolling bars on the sides of PCB editor. Normally, screen scrolling is done by clicking middle button on mouse and dragging the pointer, however when I do that in Altium I zoom the screen in/out. Can anybody help me please?:(

Answer (score 3):

In Altium, it's most convenient to scroll by right clicking and dragging. Can't remember if it worked in 16, but you can also scroll by holding some combination of shift and ctrl and using the scroll wheel. I always right click and drag, and miss it when I use other CAD software.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Altium you scroll vertically by using the mouse wheel (don't click), and horizontally by holding Shift and using the mouse wheel (again, don't click). You get used to it pretty quickly.

That being said, usually when I need to "scroll" from one side of the board to the other, I find it more efficient to zoom out so I can see the whole board, and zoom right back in on the part I need to look at.